# crossfade animation between two UIImages in objective-c doesn't fade out the first UIImage

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, core-animation

I want to crossfade between two different UIImages but for a reason i cannot figure out my first UIImage stays when the second one fades in.
Here is the sourcecode of my animation (it does a lot more than just crossfading, but the crossfading is my only problem right now).
I need all of the three animations listed below to be executed at the same time.

```
CGMutablePathRef thePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(thePath,NULL,startPoint.x, startPoint.y);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(thePath, NULL, endPoint.x, endPoint.y);

CAKeyframeAnimation *positionAnimation =[CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
positionAnimation.path=thePath;
positionAnimation.duration=ti_duration;
positionAnimation.repeatCount=0;
positionAnimation.delegate = self;
positionAnimation.autoreverses=NO;
positionAnimation.fillMode=kCAFillModeForwards;
positionAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
[self.layer addAnimation:positionAnimation forKey:s_direction];

CABasicAnimation *crossFade = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"contents"];
crossFade.duration = ti_duration;
crossFade.fromValue = (id)img_startImage.CGImage;
crossFade.toValue = (id)img_transferImage.CGImage;
[self.iv_image.layer addAnimation:crossFade forKey:@"animateContentsToTransferState"];
[self.iv_image setImage:img_transferImage];

CAAnimationGroup *theGroup = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
theGroup.duration = ti_duration;
theGroup.repeatCount = 0;
theGroup.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
theGroup.animations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:/*positionAnimation,*/ crossFade, nil]; // you can add more

[self.layer addAnimation:theGroup forKey:@"move"];

[UIView beginAnimations:@"changeSize" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:duration];
self.bounds = CGRectMake(self.bounds.origin.x, self.bounds.origin.y, self.transferSize.width, self.transferSize.height);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

The animation method containing this sourcecode is in a subclass of UIView. This subclass contains several UIImages and one UIImageView where the image to be displayed is contained in.

Have i forgotten some essential thing or why is my first image not fading away?
Can it be because it is animated from some other animation at the same time?

I hope someone can help me with this.

Greets
Maverick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of `CAAnimation`s as operations applied to the `CALayer`. The animations current state do not change the layers original contents.

When the original state seems to *snap back* at the end of the animation it is actually just the animations operation being removed, and the *real* layers state is being revealed again.

What you need to do is to register a delegate for your animation, and change the actual `self.layer.contents` when the animation ends.

First:

```
crossFade.delegate = self;
```

Then implement:

```
- (void)animationDidStop:(CABasicAnimation *)animation finished:(BOOL)flag {
    self.layer.contents = animation.toValue;
}
```

Comment: Thx for you explanation. I tried this but could not reach animationDidStop.
After some researching i found out, that i have to set `crossFade.removedOnCompletion = NO;` in addition to setting the delegate. This solved my Problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code...It worked for me.

```
-(void)crossFadeImage{

    CABasicAnimation *crossFade = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"contents"];
    crossFade.duration = 2.0;
    crossFade.fromValue  = img1.CGImage;
    crossFade.toValue = img2.CGImage;
    [self.background.layer addAnimation:crossFade forKey:@"animateContents"];
    self.background.image = img2;

}
```

Comment: as you might have seen, this is exactly the same code i have posted in my post. This was not working for me so why should your code work in my scenario?